# Can CUDA do argmax?

Tags: c, cuda, mapreduce, gpgpu

Question says it all;

Assuming each threads are doing something like

```
value=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
result=f(value);
```

where f is a device function, its easy enough to find the max result by adding an atomicMax() call, but how could you find out what the value was?

Comment: Have you looked into the reduction kernels at all? They are probably faster than atomicMax anyways.

Comment: basically f() is doing a whole pile of work, and at the end of it all I have the output values of f() but what I want is the input to f that gave the highest output. I'm working on a hacky way around it, but we'll see...

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, I was just being slow.

Comment: When you say "max result", what scope are you asking about? Thread, block or grid? The optimal solution probably isn't the same for each.

Comment: you probably already saw this, but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720267/getting-max-value-in-an-array-cuda

Comment: @jmilloy no somehow I missed that! Thanks. I've 'got it working' with a hack but when I come to the optimisation stage I'll look again. @talonmies well its actually a scope larger than the device, so I'm thinking of trying to do leveled max-ing (block max, thread max, kernel max) and see how that performs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this make sense? Just add an if statement comparing the max result to the thread's result. If it matches, save the thread's value.

```
value=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
result=f(value);
atomicMax(max,result);

if result==*max:
    max_value = value;
```

Or, perhaps you need to specify behavior if multiple threads have the max result... for example taking the lowest thread:

```
value=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
result=f(value);
atomicMax(max,result);

if result==*max:
    atomicMin(max_value,value);
```

---

That said, if you are finding the max result out of every thread, you will want to use a reduction instead of atomicMax. If I understand correctly, the atomicMax function is basically going to execute serially, whereas a reduction will be largely in parallel. When you use a reduction, you can manually track the value along with the result - that's what I do. *(Although perhaps the above if statement approach will work at the end of the reduction, too. I may have to try it in my code...)*

Comment: I don't quite understand the best way to implement what you're talking about. I had a look at using thrust, but from my reading theres no easy way to deal with using the max conditionally (i.e if this value greater than that value, give my id to the max template) Any more hints? :D

Comment: I think my code does exactly what you want. Maybe if you put it in the context of a real kernel I can help more.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of your comment about a reduction kernel, but thank you! (didn't quite implement it the same way due to particular issues with the kernel arrangement, but more or less the same as yours)

Comment: In my reduction, I have two shared memory arrays: `values` and `results`. In each comparison, I compare the results, and save the max result and the value that produced it. So at the end of the reduction, `results[0]` has the max result and `values[0]` has the value that produced it.